# How to use AND in Oz Programming language

Tags: lambda-calculus, oz

```
declare
fun {Beta E}
    case E
    of lambda(X [Y Z]) andthen {IsAtom Y}  then Z
    else nil 
     end
    end

{Browse {Beta lambda(y [y a])   }}
```

I'm trying to make a beta reducer for lambda calculus but I don't know how to append arguments for Oz which I just started using.

What I want to do is:
IsAtom Y and if(X==Y) then Z

I've tried "and, &&, &, andthen" but nothing really works.
Oz documentation is just giving me headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oz, `And` is a function not an operator. So to do an and operation you would do something like

```
{And true false}
```

Will yield `false`

[Here](https://mozart.github.io/mozart-v1/doc-1.4.0/tutorial/node6.html) is a good reference manual.

Answer (score 1):

Remember 'then' is a separator in statement syntax,  'andthen' and 'orelse' are boolean (short circuit) operators

CASESTATEMENT:

case VALUE of PATTERN then STATEMENT

IFSTATEMENT:

if BOOLEXP then STATEMENT

BOOLEXP:
BOOLEXP andthen BOOLEXP orelse BOOLEXP